# Could SqueakNOS or PharoNOS made to run an iPhone or iPad to Form a DynaBook?

Tags: iphone, ipad, smalltalk, squeak, pharo

Not considering legal issues I would be very interested if it would be possible to run one of those on the bare metal of the iPad/Phone ARM-Architecture.

Comment: Are you talking about nuking the iPhone OS and running strictly bare-metal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Squeak is running on the iPad as of today!](http://astares.blogspot.com/2010/06/squeak-on-ipad.html)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that iPad has already been jail-broken, I think it's really possible. Also, being made with an ARM processor makes it even more plausible, you already got compilers for that architecture and there seem to be ports of squeakvm to it. It would require some work though.

Comment: Indeed, Squeak's had a VM for ARM for a long time. Tim Rowledge maintains the ARM support (or did, at least), which is half the reason why I mentioned his name in my answer. (The other half is that Tim's often asked for a million dollars when someone asks him to do <insert amazing feature description>.)

Answer (score 1):

I know how to get it done, if that helps: send an iPad and a million bucks to Tim Rowledge!

Edit: Someone's got [Android working on an iPhone](http://linuxoniphone.blogspot.com/2010/04/ive-been-working-on-this-quietly-in.html), which is a pretty big step towards a SqueakNOS. In particular, I imagine if you figure out how they do the bootloading, and how to get the image on the phone, you're pretty much there?

Edit #2: Andreas Raab's [ported](http://code.google.com/p/squeak-android-vm/) Squeak to Android, so as an interim step one could always run Squeak on Android on the iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a silly attempt. The charm of an iPhone, the thing that distinguishes it from Android is that it's a controlled environment. [John Gruber calls it an app console](http://daringfireball.net/2010/05/nack_control). You can find that silly if you want, but remind me again why out of the two major mobile platforms, you choose to breach and extend the one that does NOT brag about its openness and clear documentation and freedom for third party developers. PharoNOS on Android sounds like fun, PharoNOS on the iPhone sounds like PharoNOS on a Wii. That is: You could do it, but why would you?

Comment: Because I like SqueakNOS to run on the iPhone.